# Node.js and node-sqlanywhere - No Connection Available

Tags: node.js, sybase, sqlanywhere

I have been trying to use node-sqlanywhere to query my Sybase database.

However, I cannot seem to be able to connect to the database.

```
var sqlanywhere = require('sqlanywhere');
var sqlanywhere_conn = sqlanywhere.createConnection();

var sqlanywhere_conn_params = {
    DatabaseFile: 'C:\Users\support\Dropbox\database.db',
    AutoStart: 'YES',
    UserId: 'user_id',
    Password: 'password'
};

sqlanywhere_conn.connect(sqlanywhere_conn_params, function(){
    sqlanywhere_conn.prepare('SELECT * FROM some_table WHERE some_column = ?', function (err, stmt){
        if (err) throw err;
      // do something with the statement
    });
});
```

Whether I am trying to connect to the database using **Server** attribute or the **DatabaseFile** attribute, I always get error code -2005 **No Connection Available**.

That being said, I am able to connect to my database using Interactive SQL by either specifying the server or the database file.

So.. I must be missing something here and I can't figure it out !

Thanks !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try doubling up the backslash characters, like `DatabaseFile: 'C:\\Users\\support\\Dropbox\\database.db'`.

FYI you can also ask SQL Anywhere-specific questions on http://sqlanywhere-forum.sap.com.

*Full disclosure: I work for SAP in SQL Anywhere engineering. I am responsible for both the node.js driver and the sqlanywhere-forum.sap.com site.*

Comment: Still not working :(. What should I be doing next ? I still get "No connection available", but like I mentionned, I am able through Interactive SQL to connect to my database and perform queries. I am kind of stuck on my project until I can make this work. Any and all help is appreciated :)

Comment: I feel dumb for not thinking about this earlier, but I need to realize this project with a Sybase version 9 database. I just installed SQL Anywhere 16 and it works perfectly (I did have to double the backslashes!).

So, I am guessing that you have no intention on supporting version 9 ? (which would probably make sense). The database will **eventually** be upgraded to version 16, but that is unfortunately out of my control.

Comment: I'm afraid not. Version 9 has been end-of-life'd for several years now, and the client library that the node.js driver uses didn't exist back then.

Comment: Any idea why I can successfully use your module to query my database on computer A and the same setup isn't working on computer B. The only difference is that computer B used to have SQL Anywhere 9 installed (now SQL Anywhere 16). I just created a new database with SA16 and am able just fine to connect to it using Interactive SQL but I can't get anything done in node, I always get "No connection available". The problem isn't with my syntax as it's working on computer A. Basically just wondering if you have any idea so I can investigate further. Thanks!!

Comment: I'm afraid I don't have enough information to help you. You're more likely to get a better answer if you post a new question on sqlanywhere-forum.sap.com with the full details.